# Access to VB SQL Statements

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to bring data from Access over to VB using the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard. Everything in my database is set as string and I need to keep it that way. I need to add 3 figures together and get the average of each figure in each row. My issue is that it is joining the string together rather than adding the 3 figures.

```
SELECT        
    ID, StudentID, FirstName, Surname, MCQ, Project, 
    Exam, [Password], IIF(ISNULL(MCQ), 'Not Completed', MCQ) AS Expr2, 
    IIF(ISNULL(Project), 'Not Completed', Project) AS Expr3, 
    IIF(ISNULL(Exam), 'Not Completed', Exam) AS Expr4, 
    IIF(ISNULL(MCQ), 1, MCQ) + IIF(ISNULL(Project), 1, Project) + IIF(ISNULL(Exam), 1, Exam) AS Expr5 
FROM            
    tblStudents
```

Some columns will be null and this is why I an using the `IsNull` function.

Any suggestions from anyone as a way around this?

Comment: This is the problem when you do foolish things like storing numbers as strings. You complicate things when you need to use them as numbers. Now you have to convert those strings into numbers so you can do math with them, and it's difficult to sum or average or increment them because you have to convert them then, too. It's also making your DB performance slower, because of the time doing the conversions over and over, the column won't sort correctly (in numeric order), and you're facing tons of other issues in the future. Better to fix the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, oh why would you need to keep everything stored as a string?  Anyway, wrap the IIF() statements with a CDBL() or CINT() or some cast function to force them to a numeric type for the purpose of adding the values instead of concatenating them:

```
SELECT
  ID, StudentID, FirstName, Surname, 
  MCQ, Project, Exam, [Password], 
  IIF(ISNULL(MCQ), 'Not Completed', MCQ) AS Expr2, 
  IIF(ISNULL(Project), 'Not Completed', Project) AS Expr3, 
  IIF(ISNULL(Exam), 'Not Completed', Exam) AS Expr4, 
  CINT(IIF(ISNULL(MCQ), 1, MCQ)) + 
     CINT(IIF(ISNULL(Project), 1, Project)) +
     CINT(IIF(ISNULL(Exam), 1, Exam) AS Expr5)) 
FROM tblStudents
```

Comment: Don't ask, assignment with very strange requirements!! Thanks for your answer!!